# Trying to split up a string with blank space

Tags: java, arrays, split, delimiter

I'm writing out a piece of a code that where I am trying to split up the user's input into 3 different arrays, by using the spaces in-between the values the user has entered. However, everytime i run the code i get the error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
            at Substring.main(Substring.java:18)
    Java Result: 1
```

I have tried to use a different delimiter when entering the text and it has worked fine, e.g. using a / split the exact same input normally, and did what i wanted it to do thus far.
Any help would be appreciated! 
Here's my code if needed

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Substring{
    public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String fullname = ""; //declaring a variable so the user can enter their full name
    String[] NameSplit = new String[2];
    String FirstName;
    String MiddleName;
    String LastName;

    System.out.println("Enter your full name (First Middle Last): ");
    fullname = user_input.next(); //saving the user's name in the string fullname

    NameSplit = fullname.split(" ");//We are splitting up the value of fullname every time there is a space between words
    FirstName = NameSplit[0]; //Putting the values that are in the array into seperate string values, so they are easier to handle
    MiddleName = NameSplit[1];
    LastName = NameSplit[2];

    System.out.println(fullname); //outputting the user's orginal input
    System.out.println(LastName+ ", "+ FirstName +" "+ MiddleName);//outputting the last name first, then the first name, then the middle name
    new StringBuilder(FirstName).reverse().toString();
    System.out.println(FirstName);


}
```

}

Comment: Why are you doing fullname.split("\\ ") instead of just fullname.split(" ")? Im quite certain that I have done this before and it worked.

Comment: Yeah, but you didn't tell us what you did type, so..

Comment: That shouldn't be there, my bad

Comment: I entered what has been asked of, e.g. 'Elvis John Presley'

Comment: try printing out fullname. I don't see a problem here.

Comment: hint: `next()` and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: `next()` only reads the next token (word) entered by the user. Use `nextLine()`.

Comment: @GriffeyDog this fixed it! That was a stupid mistake when initially typing up the code, my bad :) Thank you! New to stackoverflow so i have no idea how to make this the answer haha

Comment: Hint: variable names start lowerCase by convention.

Comment: And: there is **no** point in first initializing nameSplit when you later assign a new value to add. That initial new doesn't have any effect, it is just a wasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made mistakes at following places:

> fullname = user_input.next();

It should be `nextLine()` instead of just `next()` since you want to read the complete line from the Scanner.

> String[] NameSplit = new String[2];

There is no need for this step as you are doing `NameSplit = user_input.split(...)` later but it should be `new String[3]` instead of `new String[2]` since you are storing three entries i.e. First Name, Middle Name and the Last Name.

Here is the correct program:

```
class Substring {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] NameSplit = new String[3];
        String FirstName;
        String MiddleName;
        String LastName;

        System.out.println("Enter your full name (First Middle Last): ");
        String fullname = user_input.nextLine();

        NameSplit = fullname.split(" ");
        FirstName = NameSplit[0];
        MiddleName = NameSplit[1];
        LastName = NameSplit[2];

        System.out.println(fullname);
        System.out.println(LastName+ ", "+ FirstName +" "+ MiddleName);
        new StringBuilder(FirstName).reverse().toString();
        System.out.println(FirstName);
    }
}
```

Output:

> Enter your full name (First Middle Last):  John Mayer Smith
>
> Smith, John Mayer
>
> John

Comment: It's String[2] as the first value is 0, second 1, third 2 :) But thank you for the help anyway!

Comment: @L.Jones28 Just keep in mind that indices starts from `0` and while you are reserving the spaces the notion of indices doesn't hold anymore. So it should be `3` instead of just `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Split is a regular expression, you can look for one or more spaces (" +") instead of just one space (" ").

```
String[] array = s.split(" +");
```

Or you can use Strint Tokenizer

```
 String message = "MY name is ";
 String delim = " \n\r\t,.;"; //insert here all delimitators
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(message,delim);
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Scanner` breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.
hence even though you entered 'Elvis John Presley' only 'Elvis' is stored in the `fullName` variable.
You can use BufferedReader to read full line:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        fullname = reader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

or you can change the default behavior of scanner by using:
`user_input.useDelimiter("\n");` method.

Answer (score 0):

The exception clearly tells that you are exceeding the array's length. The index `2` in `LastName = NameSplit[2]` is out of array's bounds. To get rid of the error you must:

**1-** Change `String[] NameSplit = new String[2]` to `String[] NameSplit = new String[3]` because the array length should be 3.

Read more here: [ [How do I declare and initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array) ]

Up to here the error is gone but the solution is not correct yet since `NameSplit[1]` and `NameSplit[2]` are `null`, because `user_input.next();` reads only the first word (*basically until a whitespace (or '\n' if only one word) is detected). So:

**2-** Change `user_input.next();` to `user_input.nextLine();` because the `nextLine()` reads the entire line (*basically until a '\n' is detected)

Read more here: [ http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/ndale/Scanner.html ]